# Ultrawide band bandpass filter

Tags: microstrip

Please suggest how to design ultrawide band bandpass filter in ADS (Advance Design Software) using distributed Microstrip transmission lines.

Comment: if truly ultra-wide-band, you may need to consider TWO filters in series; one being DC_block and the other a Low_Pass_filter.

Comment: Do you need information about the usage of ADS or on the design of bandpass filters in general? What do you have investigated or tried so far?

Comment: I need to know how to connect various Microstrip line connections like MLIN, MTEE, MCLIN, MLOC etc. to get the design of Ultra wideband bandpass filter. With what logic these microstrip components to be connected so that bandpass filter can be designed. Please suggest.

Comment: Please define "ultra wide band". Do you mean something like half an octave, or something spanning multiple octaves?  What are your low and high cut off frequencies?

Comment: Ultrawide band means from 3.1 GHz to 10.6 GHz FCC license free band.

Answer (score 0):

A narrowband bandpass filter would normally be built with a resonator structure, widened to suit the specifications.

It's not practical to widen such a structure to *ultra-wideband*, so this would be made by simply cascading a low frequency highpass and a high frequency lowpass filter.

High frequency lowpass filters are fairly straightforward in microstrip, using alternate lengths of high and low impedance line, to look like a CLC structure. There are certain caveats, and improvements you can make, but that's the basic idea.

Low frequency highpass filters, needing as they do relatively large value series capacitors and shunt inductors, can be tricky to implement in pure microstrip, and are probably best done with discrete Ls and Cs.

Note: this answer depends on my interpretation of what exactly ultrawide means. It may change once you put some numbers in the question for the filter specifications and the substrate you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for reply.